# Android device doesn't launch activities on the screen while espresso testing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

As long as I saw in a YouTube video that an android device tends to launch and show activities that are launched in my test, I think there is a problem here, since mine doesn't react at all (the screen is always on though, animations are turned off). 
When I was trying to test the activity which runs first in the app (logically), I tried to open the app by myself while testing and somehow it worked. Now I'm testing another one and this trick doesn't work anymore.

Anyways I always get the error:
java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, STARTED, CREATED, DESTROYED]"

My test code uncludes:

> val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(HomeActivity::class.java)

And then I just check the presence of a layout element (textview or anything)

Any ideas why it may occur?
Thanks in advance

UPD: android emulator works fine.

Answer (score 6):

this also happening to my test when following codelab from google [kotlin unit test](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-test-doubles#7)

when im trying to run the test via emulator, it run perfectly, but when i run into my device, which is xiaomi redmi note 5, the error showed up like yours,

i found an answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921804/7505027) and it directed to this [github](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/857#issuecomment-965859405)
[image] [image]

i try to enable app permission "Display pop-up windows while running in the background", and when i run the test again, it passes

[image]

Comment: You are my hero!