# Espresso tests failed on real device with api 28

Tags: android, android-espresso, uitest

I downloaded test samples form https://github.com/android/testing-samples And BasicSample doesn't work on the real device with Android 9 works on Android 10. I have an exception. What is wrong? The activity doesn't even launch on the device.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[CREATED, DESTROYED, RESUMED, STARTED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(ActivityScenario.java:338)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:272)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:195)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.lambda$new$0$ActivityScenarioRule(ActivityScenarioRule.java:70)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule$$Lambda$0.get(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.before(ActivityScenarioRule.java:103)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2154)
```

Comment: Looks like you provided the wrong link.

Comment: Sorry this is the correct one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598321/androidx-test-activityscenario-java-lang-assertionerror-activity-never-becomes

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of permissions. Just allow autostart and pop-up window for this app on your android phone settings.

https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/857#issuecomment-965859405

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid link-rot), we prefer answers that provide at least a summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. Please edit your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30310834)